# Sync iCal (.ics) with Android calendar app

Tags: android, icalendar

I'm working on an app in which a user has a schedule. I'm developing a feature to let user sync his schedule with his calendar app by clicking a button.

Our API returns an iCal link (a .ics file). On iOS, it was really simple to make this link open in the calendar app and sync with calendar. When a change is made on the user schedule, the calendar app updates the calendar correctly.

But, on Android, I have issues making it works. I've look for solution, but there doesn't seem to have an easy way to sync an iCal file with the calendar app.

Is there any intent or way to sync iCal with user's calendar app?

Comment: Hi @Mathbl guy, I have a same problem like you. Did you find out any solution yet?

Comment: Nah. I ended opening Google Calendar in a Webview, and make the user add the calendar manually by pasting the link *shrugs*.